# Memory could not be written when changing path of file pointer

Tags: c, file-pointer

My code below is running well however when I change the path of the file pointer for both input and output file from const char *input_file = "input.txt";to ../data/input.txt" for the input I get the below error 
[Memory could not be written error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVt4P.png)

How do i change the path of the file pointer to the correct file in a directory
Below is my main program code

```
   int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        const char *input_file = "input.txt";
        const char *output_file = "output.txt";

        int i, j, k, n;
        int cars_arrived, total_cars, max_queue_len, running_queue_len;
        int arrival_time, wait_time, max_wait_time, running_wait_time; 
        int departure_period, departure_timer;
        int light_timer, light_duration[3] = {0, 0, 0};
        int time, increment, runtime;
        int avg_wait_time, avg_queue_len;
        double arrival_rate, lambda;

        Light light;
        queue_t *queue = (queue_t *)malloc(sizeof(queue));
        parameters *param_list = read_input_file(input_file, &n);

        FILE *output_fp = fopen(output_file, "w");
        fprintf(output_fp, "%s\n", STUDENT_ID);

      parameters* read_input_file(const char *fname, int *num_scenarios)
{
    int i, j, k, idx, value;
    keyword key;
    parameters *param_list = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");

            /* write the output to the file */
            fprintf(output_fp, "Arrival rate: %d cars per min\n", param_list[i][0]);
            fprintf(output_fp, "Departure rate: %d s per car\n", param_list[i][1]);
            fprintf(output_fp, "Runtime: %d min\n", param_list[i][2]);
            fprintf(output_fp, "Time increment:  %d ms\n", param_list[i][3]);
            fprintf(output_fp, "Light sequence: Green %d s; Amber %d s; Red %d s\n", 
                    param_list[i][6], param_list[i][5], param_list[i][4]);
            fprintf(output_fp, "Average length: %d cars\n", avg_queue_len);
            fprintf(output_fp, "Maximum length: %d cars\n", max_queue_len);
            fprintf(output_fp, "Average wait: %d s\n", avg_wait_time / 1000);
            fprintf(output_fp, "Maximum wait: %d s\n", max_wait_time / 1000);
        }

        fclose(output_fp);
        /* free memory */
        free(queue);
        free(param_list);

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: I see a lot of code that's irrelevant to the problem, but no code for the `read_input_file` function. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Edited to remove irrelevant code

Comment: And, where's the `read_input_file` function?

Comment: Guessing it fails to open the file (because the current directory is not `data` or a sibling of it), `n` is never initialized or set to 0 in the read function, and then your loop goes hog wild on some bad value thereof.

Comment: But you should definitely still edit to include the read function (and not just the first few lines of it plopped down in the middle of main as it is as of this moment)